# Calculating complex integral for different values of $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know how to compute the following integral. I think it might be possible to use the Residue Theorem to compute it, but the $\sin\theta$ inside the cosine function is throwing me off.

$$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} d \theta e^{-\cos (\theta)} \cos (n \theta+\sin(\theta))$$

I am not very sure how to manipulate the integrand so that it becomes somewhat easier. Maybe something like this could work because we could split the integral in several smaller integrals, but the fact that there are still nested trig functions bothers me because I do not know how to deal with them:

$$\cos(n\theta + sin(\theta)) = \cos (\sin (\theta)) \cos (\theta n)-\sin (\sin (\theta)) \sin (\theta n)$$

(Where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$). I need to give the result for all $n$. Any help would be very appreciated.

**Update**. I simplified the integrand a little. From the last expression, one can see that $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\sin\theta) = 0$ because the function $\sin(\sin\theta)$ is periodic in $\theta$ with period $2\pi$ and for both $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$ it equals zero. Therefore the integrand can be reduced to:

$$I_n = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)\cos(\sin\theta)$$
Which still seems kinda difficult to compute.

Comment: I would have written $J_n=$ same thing with $\sin(n\theta+\sin\theta)$ and looked at $I_n+iJ_n$, and then changed variable to $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Another way to look at ancient mathematician's hint is to use $\cos(z)=\operatorname{Re}\left(e^{-iz}\right)$ for $\cos(n\theta+\sin(\theta))$

Comment: If I use that advice, $\cos(z) = \operatorname{Re}(e^{-iz})$, I get at the same thing i wrote in my original post. I think there must be something I'm not understanding.

Comment: Notice that although $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\sin(\theta))\,\mathrm{d}\theta=0$, $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\cos(\theta)}\sin(\sin(\theta))\sin(n\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ is not necessarily $0$. In fact, it is $-\pi\operatorname{sgn}(n)\frac{(-1)^n}{|n|!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{{}-\cos(\theta)}\cos(n\theta+\sin(\theta))\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\Re\left(\int_0^{2\pi}e^{{}-\cos(\theta)-in\theta-i\sin(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\right)\tag1\\
&=\Re\left(\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-e^{i\theta}}\,e^{-in\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\right)\tag2\\
&=\Re\left(\frac1i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-e^{i\theta}}\,e^{-i(n+1)\theta}\,\mathrm{d}e^{i\theta}\right)\tag3\\
&=\Re\left(\frac1i\oint_{|z|=1}e^{-z}z^{-n-1}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)\tag4\\[3pt]
&=2\pi\Re\left(\Res_{z=0}\left(e^{-z}z^{-n-1}\right)\right)\tag5\\[3pt]
&=2\pi\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}[n\ge0]\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\cos(z)=\Re\left(e^{-iz}\right)$
$(2)$: $\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$
$(3)$: $\mathrm{d}e^{i\theta}=ie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$
$(4)$: substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$
$(5)$: [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)
$(6)$: use the power series for $e^z$ to get $\left[z^n\right]e^{-z}$

Comment: Okay, this seems very reasonable. Let me work through this just to see if I have any trouble. The only thing I don't understand is why you used the property listed in $(1)$. Isn't $\cos(z) = \operatorname{Re}(e^{iz})$ too, without the negative sign? Why did you choose this particular identity instead of the one I mention?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really was useful and a nice way of solving the problem quickly. I have only one question. How did you know, in the line labelled as $(5)$, that you could cancel out the $1/i$ multiplying the integral with the $i$ in the residue theorem? Is it obvious? I thought you had to compute the residues first and then check whether or not the i's cancel.

Comment: I used $\operatorname{Re}\left(e^{-ix}\right)$ because it works better with $e^{{}-\cos(x)}$ to give $e^{-e^{ix}}$ so that then we can use $z=e^{ix}$

Comment: In $(5)$, we know that the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues, so $1/i$ times the integral is $2\pi$ times the sum of the residues. Then, $\operatorname{Re}(2\pi z)=2\pi\operatorname{Re}(z)$.

Comment: Thanks, this was fantastic. All my doubts have been perfectly answered :)